# Determining whether all items in an IShellItemArray come from the same directory

Tags: c++, winapi, com

Let's say you want to determine whether all items in an `IShellItemArray` belong to the same parent directory.  How might you do that?

This is what I've come up with, but I was wondering if there's a more efficient or otherwise more acceptable way (it's based on the behaviors described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishellitemarray-getpropertystore#remarks)):

```
HRESULT ItemsInSameDirectory(IShellItemArray* psia, BOOL* fSameDir)
{
    HRESULT hr;

    CComPtr<IPropertyStore> pPropStore;
    hr = psia->GetPropertyStore(GPS_FASTPROPERTIESONLY, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pPropStore));
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        return hr;
    }

    wil::unique_prop_variant pv;
    hr = pPropStore->GetValue(PKEY_ItemFolderPathDisplay, &pv);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        return hr;
    }

    *fSameDir = (pv.vt == VT_LPWSTR) ? TRUE : FALSE;

    return S_OK;
}
```

Comment: How about  checking to see if they have the same parent?

Comment: And using `IShellItem::Compare`?

Comment: Haven't you asked the same question just days ago, and received useful comments on why that question doesn't have an answer? Why did you delete the other question and start over asking the same one again?

Comment: My last question incorrectly assumed that all items in an `IShellItemArray` share the same parent.  And I was asking how to find it.  My proposed solution to that problem naively grabbed the first `IShellItem` in the array and obtained its parent directory.  But now I realize that was wrong, so I'm starting over and asking how to determine whether all items in the array in fact share the same parent.  Also, sometimes I remove questions because I tend to get downvoted and don't want to keep losing rep.

Comment: Depends on what you mean exactly by parent. PKEY_ItemFolderPathDisplay is not guaranteed to always exist (virtual folders, etc.). One way is to QI each ShellItem for IParentAndItem, call GetParentAndItem and compare absolute parent PIDLs.